# How to access data member in a list, with different type than my list

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing a program with a list of the type Artikel and in the list there are several elements that each contains 4 data members, 2 int and 2 string. The list is sorted by int artikelNr and the function below is supposed to add a new Artikel to the list at the right spot with its artikelNr in mind. Although since the list is of the type Artikel and the data member I am comparing with is Int I get the error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Artikel'|

I have tried to make an iterator *it to the list of the type int but it does not work since the list is of the type Artikel.

```
void Lager::lagg_till_registret(Artikel funkArtikel)  
{
bool check = false;
list<Artikel>::iterator it = listaMedArtiklar.begin();
while(check == false){
   if(funkArtikel.artikelNr < (*it)->artikelNr){
        listaMedArtiklar.insert (it,funkArtikel);
        check = true;
    }
    else
        it++;
}
}
```

Comment: Try `it->artikelNr`. (`*it` isn't a pointer.)

Comment: @molbdnilo What if `Artikel` is a pointer !?

Comment: @DieterLücking "base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Artikel'" kind of suggests that it isn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried it->artikelNr and I no longer have the error about the type, instead though, I got two of these: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)|

Comment: @EmilCoder If `artikelNr` is a function, you need the "()", but you didn't write any.

Comment: @molbdnilo Neither is `it`. It's an `iterator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to solve it is this:

```
void Lager::lagg_till_registret(Artikel funkArtikel)  
{
bool check = false;
list<Artikel>::iterator it = listaMedArtiklar.begin();
while(check == false){
    if(funkArtikel.artikelNr < it->artikelNr){
        listaMedArtiklar.insert (it,funkArtikel);
        check = true;
    }
    else
        it++;
   }
}
```

Also you can do this (this is equal to the first one, but looks ugly)

```
if(funkArtikel.artikelNR < (*it).artikelNr)
```

Comment: I tried it and it removed the previous error about the different types but now I recieved another error instead: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)                                        Any idea what that means? Thanks for taking your time btw!

Comment: @EmilCoder More code is needed to check this. Put paranthesis if `artikelNr` is a function. If not, the error belongs to another portion of the code.

Comment: @EmilCoder I suggest you to use a proper IDE (like Eclipse) to write your code. That makes it easier to debug your code. A good one would show that you're missing the paranthesis while you're writing.

Comment: Ok, I can send all the files through drive if thats ok. artikelNr is an int variable btw.                                                       https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzOhNm8EsIbMfmk0d0l3ZmNQSTNyZHA4ZTB5bW84Q3NGenVsVzNJUkFlUEtfYWc0X2xYcmM&authuser=0

Comment: Ok, I have only used Code blocks and Microsoft visual c++ studio so far but will definitely try that one out!

Comment: @EmilCoder Doesn't the compiler show the line which gives the error?

Comment: Oh yes it does, it is on the line with '    if(funkArtikel.artikelNr < it->artikelNr){'

Comment: @EmilCoder Maybe you should write `funkArtikel().artikelNr` ?

Comment: Hm, it makes the error disappear but I get a new one. Though I doubt it is correct since funkArtikel isn't a function but a variable of the type Artikel, or am I wrong?

Comment: @EmilCoder I don't know whether you defined `funkArtikel` as a function or a variable. Put the code into the question and let us check.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I added () after artikelNr as someone suggested below and it worked. Apperently I forgot artikelNr was defined 'int artikelNr();' and not 'int artikelNr;'. Was a few weeks since I worked with this program.. Thank you very much for your patient and help!

Comment: @EmilCoder You're welcome. I'm here to try and help as much as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall it well but if yout dereference a variable in c++ you don't need the '->' operator. Try to use '.' instead:

```
void Lager::lagg_till_registret(Artikel funkArtikel)  
{
bool check = false;
list<Artikel>::iterator it = listaMedArtiklar.begin();
while(check == false){
   if(funkArtikel.artikelNr < (*it).artikelNr){
        listaMedArtiklar.insert (it,funkArtikel);
        check = true;
    }
    else
        it++;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried the '.' at first, but it did not work and I got the error: 'std::list<Artikel>::iterator' has no member named 'artikelNr'|

Comment: it is 'std::list<Artikel>::iterator' but (*it) is Artikel

Comment: Yes, the iterator is of the type Artikel and the data member I am trying to access is of the type int. Sorry, I dont really get it?

Comment: the iterator is a pointer to some data of type Artikel, you can access to the referenced data in two ways when coding in c++. `it->member`, `(*it).member`. When you write 'it.member' you'll get an error, it is a pointer not a class/struct. I hope it helps

Comment: As I saw in other answer: to access a function you must use '()' after the function name `funkArtikel.artikelNr() < it->artikelNr()`, `funkArtikel.artikelNr() < (*it).artikelNr()` might work.